# Quick way to numerically cancel exponentials

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have a problem with exponentials and the use of the commands `N` and `Collect`. I am trying to write a code that generates a very large list of polynomials on a variable x which are needed as input for an external program. In order to create the proper input for this program, I have to write the polynomials in a numerical format and not a symbolic one. A simple nesting of the commands

```
Collect[N[f[x],precision],x]
```

does (almost every time) what I want. The problem with my polynomials is that they come after the cancellation of some exponentials, of which the two commands above took care of so far. As a simple example,

```
In[]:= Collect[
 N[-4*E^(2*Pi*(4 + x))*(E^(-(Pi*x) - Pi*(8 + x))/2 - 
      8*E^(-(Pi*x) - Pi*(8 + x))*Pi) + 
   8*E^(-(Pi*x) + 2*Pi*(4 + x) - Pi*(8 + x))*Pi*x], x]
Out[]= 98.531 + 25.1327 x
```

However, the only instance when this happens to fail is when one of the polynomials is of degree 0, in which case the cancellation of the exponentials doesn't happen anymore:

```
In[]:= Collect[N[-4*E^(-(Pi*x) + 2*Pi*(4 + x) - Pi*(8 + x))], x]
Out[]= -4. 2.71828^(-3.14159 x + 6.28319 (4. + x) - 
  3.14159 (8. + x))
```

A trivial swap of `N` and `Collect` doesn't solve the issue. After changing the arguments of the exponentials, the problem seems to appear if I have some parenthesis `()` and some noninteger number in front of my variable x. I would like to make use of `Simplify` to solve the problem, but since the program is already demanding and the process has to be iterated tons of times, I need to find a faster way to fix this issue instead of using `Simplify` each time. The only other solution which seemed to work is nesting the commands `N[ExpToTrig[N[Collect[... ,x]]]]` (it's not enough to apply `N[ ]` once), but I am not sure of how much it is reliable on the long run and (if and) how much it is faster than `Simplify`. Is there some quick fix to the problem that I don't know of? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

collect[expr_, wp_ : MachinePrecision, var : _Symbol : x] :=
 expr // Simplify // Collect[#, var] & // N[#, wp] &

poly1 = -4*
    E^(2*Pi*(4 + x))*(E^(-(Pi*x) - Pi*(8 + x))/2 - 
      8*E^(-(Pi*x) - Pi*(8 + x))*Pi) + 
   8*E^(-(Pi*x) + 2*Pi*(4 + x) - Pi*(8 + x))*Pi*x;

poly1 // collect

(* 98.531 + 25.1327 x *)

poly1 // collect[#, 10] &

(* 98.53096491 + 25.13274123 x *)

poly2 = -4*E^(-(Pi*x) + 2*Pi*(4 + x) - Pi*(8 + x));

poly2 // collect

(* -4. *)

poly2 // collect[#, 8] &

(* -4.0000000 *)
```

**EDIT:** To avoid `Simplify`, use `ExpandAll`

```
collect2[expr_, wp_ : MachinePrecision, var : _Symbol : x] := 
 expr // ExpandAll // Collect[#, var] & // N[#, wp] &

poly1 // collect2

(* 98.531 + 25.1327 x *)

poly2 // collect2

(* -4. *)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Doesn't this always use Simplify on each expression you are giving as input? Because my question was whether this can be avoided or not. Applying Simplify to a full and large amount of polynomials only because of a problem with a very small subset of them is the real problem which I'm trying to evade

Comment: Yes it uses `Simplify`. I didn't get to the part of your question where it said you wanted something else.

Comment: @Gnrdgr1594 On the two examples, I find nothing faster than `poly // Simplify // N // Expand`. (I'm a bit surprised, because `Simplify` can be slow, but not here.)

Comment: 3rd arg of `Collect` can be useful here, `Collect[expr, var, fun]` with `fun` equal to `Simplify` or `ExpandAll`

Comment: @I.M. It's kinda slow, though.

Answer (score 1):

@BobHanlon's `Simplify` solution is pretty fast, and the tweak below is a little faster. `Simplify` is not always fast, but without an example to show it is slower, it seems the way to go.  A fairly quick way, though twice as slow as `Simplify`, is to evaluate the exponential at a numerical value of `x`.  Given that the exponentials cancel out anyway, the coefficients are really constant functions of `x`.

```
poly1 = -4*
    E^(2*Pi*(4 + x))*(E^(-(Pi*x) - Pi*(8 + x))/2 - 
      8*E^(-(Pi*x) - Pi*(8 + x))*Pi) + 
   8*E^(-(Pi*x) + 2*Pi*(4 + x) - Pi*(8 + x))*Pi*x;

poly1 // Simplify // N // Expand // RepeatedTiming
poly1 /. E^y_ :> E^(y /. x -> 0.) // Expand // RepeatedTiming

poly1 // Simplify // Collect[#, x] & // N // RepeatedTiming   (* Bob's Simplify *)
poly1 // ExpandAll // Collect[#, x] & // N // RepeatedTiming  (* Bob's ExpandAll *)
Collect[poly1, x, Simplify] // N // RepeatedTiming            (* I.M.'s variants *)
Collect[poly1, x, ExpandAll] // N // RepeatedTiming 
(*
  {0.0000159242, 98.531 + 25.1327 x}
  {0.00003259,   98.531 + 25.1327 x}

  {0.0000242625, 98.531 + 25.1327 x}
  {0.00457064,   98.531 + 25.1327 x}
  {0.00163333,   98.531 + 25.1327 x}
  {0.00708584,   98.531 + 25.1327 x}
*)
```

The second example is a little small for a speed test, but it was included because the OP's first method didn't handle it.  We can make a more complicated example by raising `poly1` to a power.  The `Simplify` method is still a little faster than the others. Although @BobHanlon's `Simplify @* Collect` slows down relatively, it's still faster than `ExpandAll @* Collect`.

```
poly2 = poly1^10;

poly2 // Simplify // N // Expand // RepeatedTiming // First
poly2 /. E^y_ :> E^(y /. x -> 0.) // Expand // RepeatedTiming // First

poly2 // Simplify // Collect[#, x] & // N // RepeatedTiming // First
poly2 // ExpandAll // Collect[#, x] & // N // RepeatedTiming // First
Collect[poly2, x, Simplify] // N // RepeatedTiming // First
Collect[poly2, x, ExpandAll] // N // RepeatedTiming // First
(*
  0.0000417911
  0.0000496085

  0.000470552
  0.00525135
  0.00515953
  0.13587
*)
```

Comment: I was updating the question right now and then I saw your new message. Thanks for your time. I did some runs with a subset of my data and I confirm that using `Simplify` and `Collect` is a bit faster than `ExpandAll`. However, I found a faster fix: using `N[ ,precision]` before `Collect` reduces by a factor of 3x the time needed (I guess because I'm truncating the numbers to play with `Collect`?), but will not get rid of the ugly exponentials. However, using the option `Collect[N[expr,precision],x,ReplaceAll[#,x->0]&]` does the job very efficiently. I will add a detailed answer in a bit.